# Lock Fob and lock button work only with ignition switch on: 2001 Infiniti 130t

Tags: locks, ignition-key, fob, infiniti

Just got my 2001 Infinite i30t back from the shop. I have noticed that the fob and door button both now only work to lock and unlock the car with the key in the ignition switch and turned to the on position. Otherwise neither the button nor the fob do anything. The key itself still unlocks the driver's side side and still starts the car.

The battery had been at mostly discharged for some period but seems to be charged now (the shop replaced the accessory belt which drives the alternator - the car had run for a bit with a low battery).